# Count running processes using wc and ps

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

I tried using `ps r > log | wc log` but this returns `Ambiguous output redirect.`. 
Can someone explain why and provide another solution?

Comment: Rather than using a `|` you could use `&&` that should work.

Comment: [`/proc/loadavg` should also include the number of running processes](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipe symbol ("|") redirects the output of one program to the input of another.

You however use ">" to redirect `wc`'s output to a file named log AND at the same time want to redirect the output to STDIN of `wc` (which won't use it as you provide an input file for `wc`).

So, you want one of the following (Hint: the latter solution is better as it doesn't create extra files.)

```
ps r > log ; wc log
```

or

```
ps r|wc
```

BTW: you might want `wc` to count lines, so `wc -l` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing redirection and piping

```
ps r > log # redirects ps output to a file called log (over writing any contents of log)
```

What you want is

```
ps r | wc # this connects the output of ps to the input of wc
```

If you wanted to use your methodology, then you would need to do the following

```
ps r > log; wc log
```

meaning, `ps` redirects its output to a file called log, then the command `wc` is run on the file `log`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ps` to do this is unreliable -- a process' arguments can contain newlines. A better alternative on Linux is to use `/proc/loadavg` like so:

```
awk '{ gsub("[0-9]+/", "") ; print $4 }' /proc/loadavg
```

Comment: I'm so confused about this. `top` shows 74 processes, `ps -A | wc -l` shows 76. `ps -A --no-headers | wc -l` shows 75. Who is right? Who is wrong? Counting the actual number of processes from `ps -A` indicates that there are 74 processes. The point is, the 74th process is the ps command.